# error starting node app on heroku

Tags: heroku, mean-stack

im trying to push a mean stack project to heroku, but it wont start on heroku's server. it keeps giving me the following from the applications log:

```
2017-12-12T23:59:32.528690+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2017-12-12T23:59:32.529607+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! atl@0.0.0 start: 
`ng serve`
2017-12-12T23:59:32.529706+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2017-12-12T23:59:32.529925+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-12-12T23:59:32.530127+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 
atl@0.0.0 start script.
2017-12-12T23:59:32.530306+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably 
not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output 
above.
2017-12-12T23:59:32.535107+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-12-12T23:59:32.535281+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log 
of this run can be found in:
2017-12-12T23:59:32.535429+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     
/app/.npm/_logs/2017-12-12T23_59_32_531Z-debug.log
2017-12-12T23:59:32.626726+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from 
starting to crashed
2017-12-12T23:59:32.613442+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with 
status 1
```

i don''t know where to look for this problem, please let me know if i need to upload any files to help with this error, thank you in advance.

Comment: Your app crashed. You should try to find log data on heroku.com. E.g. on the app's dashboard --> More --> View logs. Or open the console and look for the mentioned log file. You can also use the CLI.

Comment: @MikaS I did and that's what is above, the logs

Comment: What about the content of 2017-12-12T23_59_32_531Z-debug.log?

Comment: @MikaS I can't access it, or I don't know-how to.

Comment: At the dashboard on heroku.com, find the More menu, choose Run console, run bash, run **cd .npm/_logs/**, run **cat 2017-12-12T23_59_32_531Z-debug.log**. Hopefully, that works.